# Problem sharing via email in Photos app on Mac

Tags: macos, photos.app, file-sharing

As of yesterday, I can't send a photo from Photos app on my Mac via email (through the 'share' feature). I've been sharing this way all week and now, nothing. No message, it just doesn't do anything. Help?

Comment: In System Preferences > Extensions > Share Menu, is Mail enabled?

Comment: mgiordi, the box for Mail is checked but is greyed out. What's weird is that I've been sharing this way all week until a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2):

For me, (with the same problem), the issue was that Apple Mail was not the default mail client (Thunderbird was).

Mail > Preferences > General

Changed "default email reader" to Mail.app and Presto!  email appeared in the share menu.